# Rails Single Table Inheritance with dynamically defined classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In using Rails STI (Single Table Inheritance), I have defined a model named Poi (point of interest).

Our app's requirement dictate that subclasses of Poi (like Restaurant, Club, etc) must be created in an Admin::Categories view (where it has a `class_name` string input field), so that an Admin should be able to create a new subclass at anytime without needing a programmer to open a new ruby file with an empty (useless) subclass and re-deploy the app.

At the same time, IF in the future we want to specify different behavior (either instance/class methods) for a subclass of Poi, we can just create that ruby file, but that should be an option and not mandatory. The same goes for a different form with different fields for that subclass: we just need to setup a `partial_name_for_form` instance method in that subclass that returns a string with the partial name and the views will render that accordingly. If none is found, the default Poi views are rendered.

Since Rails raises an error if you try to instanciate a new Poi object with 'type' attribute that doesn't match a subclass of Poi (so the subclass MUST be previously defined), we came up with the following solution for dynamically creating the Poi subclasses based on class_name:

1. An `after_create` hook in model Category that defines the new class immediately using this code: `Object.const_set(category.class_name, Class.new(Poi))`
2. A `require_dependency` call in model Poi file (because it's in the autoload path) to require the ruby files for the subclasses we have eventually created hardcoded subclasses (only if the file exists):

`Category.all.each do |category|`

`require_dependency category.class_name.underscore if File.exist (File.join("app","models","pois","#{category.class_name.underscore}.rb"))`

`end`

3. An initializer that defines all remaining classes (by 'remaining' I mean other subclasses that don't still have their own ruby file defining them) using the same code in #1, but checking `if Object.const_defined? category.class_name` first (because the ones defined by require_dependency don't need to be re-defined).

Even tough all this complexity made we almost regret using STI in the first place, it was working fine - **in development**.

But in **production** environment, after the creation of a new category providing `class_name`, the Class doesn't get defined, because when trying to create a new Poi with that subclass is raising an error `uninitialized constant`.

I confirmed in Rails console in Production environment that the after_create hook IS working, because the class is being defined there. My wild guess is that because we use Unicorn, this bug could be related to the forking of the application code, but I have no clue how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

> **10.5 require_dependency and Initializers**
>
> One could think about doing some require_dependency calls in an initializer to make sure certain constants are loaded upfront, for example as an attempt to address the gotcha with STIs.
>
> Problem is, in development mode autoloaded constants are wiped if there is any relevant change in the file system. If that happens then we are in the very same situation the initializer wanted to avoid!

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html. From what I read here, it seems `require_dependency` in `initializer` works differently between environments. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912418/using-dynamically-created-classes-in-a-single-table-inheritance-mechanism) - see if that helps.

I would avoid creating dynamic constants because of a broken model.

Comment: emaillenin, thanks for the reply, but I had read that in the Rails guide and saw the previous SO question as well. As far as I understand, the Rails guide is clear about NOT using `require_dependency` in an *initializer*; in the same topic you linked to the Rails guide, you'll see it finishes with the phrase `Calls to require_dependency have to be strategically written in autoloaded spots.`. That's why I stated on item 2 that I'm using `require_dependency` inside a Model, which is an autoloaded spot.

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate why what we have is a 'broken model' ? We're trying to follow Rails guidelines here using Single Table Inheritance.

Comment: `Single Table Inheritance` is fine but dynamically creating entities/models is not. It leads to the problems that you have mentioned in your post already. You are making changes to the way Rails initializes the application. So it is not future proof when you are upgrading Rails itself.